# Какие слова называются общенародными, социально ограниченными, диалектно ограниченными?

Tags: значение-слов, терминология

Объясните, пожалуйста, какие слова называются:

1) общенародными;
2) социально ограниченными;
3) диалектно ограниченными.

Comment: elenaalisa,форум не выполняет домашнее  задание. Вы выполните, а мы - проверим. Для того чтобы выполнить это задание,надо обратиться к словарю. Если у вас нет словарей,на Грамоте.ру есть хорошие словари. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **общенародные** — те, которые употребляет *весь народ*;

2) **социально ограниченные** — *профессионализмы, термины, жаргонная лексика, арготизмы;*

3) **диалектно ограниченные** — *областные* слова, южный и северный *диалекты*, *говоры* (изба, голицы, гай, базар).